# Composition of an injective and surjective function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the composition of injective and surjective function bijective? Why?

Comment: No. Every function can be factorized as a composition of an injective and a surjective function, however not every function is bijective.

Answer (score 2):

No, suppose the domain of the injective function is greater than one, and the surjective function has a singleton set as a codomain.

Or let the injective function be the identity function. Then your question reduces to 'is a surjective function bijective?'

Comment: A function that maps to a single element can hardly be surjective.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the codomain of the surjective function is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

$f: \{a,b\} \to \{a\}$ with $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = a$ is a surjective function.

$g: \{a\} \to \{a\}$ with $g(a)=(a)$ is a bijective function.

Clearly $g\circ f: \{a,b\} \to \{a\}$ is not a bijective function.

Answer (score 0):

No. Define $f: \{a\} \to \{b,c,d\}$ by $f(a)=b$, and $g: \{b,c,d\}\to \{e,h\}$ by $g(b)=e$, $g(c)=g(d)=h$. $f$ is injective, and $g$ is surjective. Then $g\circ f: \{a\}\to\{e,h\}$ by $g\circ f(a)=g(b)=e$ which is not surjective, thus not bijective.